# Would Emacs Manages Files and Writes in HDD in Someway That Would Cause Malfunction in it?

Tags: dired, writing

Noticed here that `var` partition is constantly returning error in boot process, compelling me to do a `fsck` frequentily.

Once it has been used to do high-level using, in `dired`, `org`, `tramp`, `Bookmarks+` `major-modes`, `DocView`, `EIMP` to write text files, read them, copy, move and with Terminal using too, would Emacs constant using causes some kind of malfunction in the HDD?

Comment: It sounds more like you have a dodgy hard-drive, and you should make certain that it's well backed up so that you can replace it.  I'm pretty confident that, unless there are bugs in the underlying OS or filesystem itself, it shouldn't be possible for Emacs (or any other high-level program) to cause HDD malfunctions.  I'll leave it to someone who knows low-level filesystem details to say something more definitive, but if I were you I would be taking steps to replace that drive.